# how to make a UIImageView rotate around its center

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

im making an ios app in xcode 4 and I need a square UIImageView to rotate around its center to the number of degrees I give it.

does anyone know how to do this??

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImageView *yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:'anyimageyouhave'];

[yourImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation('anyangleyouwish')];
```

This works for me. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: ok, that let me move it, how do you set the point around which it rotates?

Comment: @Camper2025 I thought it is only transforming at the center. So how did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in real time you should draw it into a CALayer that you create your self and then add to you views root CALayer, then use the method [CALayer setAffineTransform:] to rotate it. You then need to set up the layers bounds so the the point (0,0) is at the point you want to rotate around, ie your min-x and miny-y bounds should equal to -(max-x) and -(max-y) bounds to rotate around the exact centre.